# Android - Firebase quick start guide

Tags: android, firebase, installation, setup-project

I am a little confused,

I started learning Firebase from [this documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/setup.html) , but as I started integrating other components several things didn't match ok.

Then I found [this other site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) that has a different use of Gradle instructions and overall setup.

I know that Google bought Firebase, so should I use the latter? Should I use both? How much do they differ one from another?

I started using: `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2`

but then I see people using instead: `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0`

And I had even seen some people who has both in their Gradle file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big yellow banner on that documentation:

> YOU'RE VIEWING THE LEGACY DOCS. THEY ARE DEPRECATED AS OF MAY 18, 2016.
>   These docs are for version 2.5.2 and below of the Java SDK. Go to our [current docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/), or see our [Android migration guide](http://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: Well I actually never saw that message haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by registering your app in firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/

if you follow the instruction [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) then you could successfuly integrate firebase service